# YARN Error / yarn create react-app myapp ERROR

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

Last night I installed Yarn on my Windows OS, when I send the command `yarn create react-app` I have the next error:

```
yarn create v1.22.19
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-react-app@5.0.1" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
'C:\Users\NG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
**error Command failed.**
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\NG By ROG\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
Arguments: myapp
Directory: C:\Users\NG By ROG\Desktop\REACT
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\NG By ROG\Desktop\REACT>
```

I try with every tutorial on YouTube, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

This Error Occurs On Windows, If your User Profile/Name has a space in it.

**Solution 1**:- Try creating a Windows User without any space on it - Example - NGByROG2. Then Try `yarn create`

**Solution 2**:- Create the folders

1. c:\yarn\cache
2. c:\yarn\packages

and give Read/Write Permission & then run the below commands

```
yarn config set cache-folder c:\yarn\cache
yarn config set prefix c:\yarn\packages
```

Restart the system & then try `yarn create` - It should work.